# Installing Remote System Explorer in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Kepler and I am trying to install the Remote system explorer using the repositories. When I search for it in Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler I find it, but when I attempt to install I get the error:

```
 "Installing software" has encountered a problem
 An error occurred while collecting the items to be installed

 An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.dstore.core,3.3.201.201309112143
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.rse.core,3.3.100.201307171557
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.rse.core,3.4.100.201307171557
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.rse.dstore,3.4.100.201309112143
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.rse,3.5.0.201309112143
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.rse.files.ui,3.2.200.201307171555
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.rse.subsystems.files.core,3.3.1.201306281330
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.rse.terminals,1.2.100.201308011444
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.rse.ui,3.3.100.201306211706
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tm.terminal,3.2.100.201308011444
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.tm.terminal,3.2.100.201308011444
```

does anyone know why it cannot find these packages? Or how I can go about getting them?

Answer (score 7):

For Kepler, Remote System Explorer is available in the Eclipse Market Place. In help go to Eclipse Market Place and type "remote" in the filter. RSE is the first result in the search.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to installed RSE. It comes installed in Eclipse Kepler 4.3.

Just go to

```
Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Remote System Details (or maybe Remote Systems)
```

and then add your remote system details.

Comment: RSE is not included in all the Eclipse downloads, for some it must be installed.