# How do you access remote files on Eclipse Kelper?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse Kelper and I need to work on a project where the source code is on a remote linux server.

I tried to follow this guide, however "Remote Systems Explorer" does not come up in the plugins option (Event if I try to use the helio repo)
http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fgettingstarted%2Fg_start.html

I also tried this, however I do not get the option for `Remote System Details (or maybe Remote Systems)` under Window > Show View > Other:
[Installing Remote System Explorer in Eclipse Kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202640/installing-remote-system-explorer-in-eclipse-kepler)

Is there something I am missing? Surely I should be able to connect to a remote server using the latest version of eclipse?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: There are several different Eclipse downloads, exactly what is included varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Remote System Explorer (which is installed on eclipse for EE) use the

1. Marketplace
2. Help -> Install New Software
3. Install kepler/Juno for EE

It will appear on View.